# Do exist different upper triangular matrices sharing the same singular values?

Tags: matrices, svd

Do exist different upper triangular matrices sharing the same singular values?

For example, I have the upper triangular matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}
10 & 5 & 30\\ 
0 & 3 & 10\\ 
0 & 0 & 15
\end{pmatrix}$$

and with Singular Value Decomposition, I find that it has a singular vector $$(36.427657,     5.118751, 2.413333)$$

So, my concern is, are there any other upper triangular matrices

$$\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c\\ 
0 &  d& e\\ 
0 & 0 & f
\end{pmatrix}$$

with the same singular values?

Comment: Any upper triangular matrix $T$ and $-T$ have the same singular values.

Comment: @Jonathan The title is not much clear with respect to the question formulated. I'll edit with something different, then check if it is fine for you.

Comment: @user Thank you for that!!

Comment: @Jonathan1234 You are welcome! In this way it seems better indeed. Bye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can easily find other upper triangular matrices with the same singular values as follows.

Let indicate with $A$ the upper triangular matrix in hand and $M$ is an upper triangular orthogonal matrix (i.e. diagonal), then $MA$ is upper triangular too, moreover $MAA^TM^T=MAA^TM^{-1}$ is [similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity) to $AA^T$ and then $MA$ share with $A$ the same singular values.

For example:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & -1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
10 & 5 & 30\\ 
0 & 3 & 10\\ 
0 & 0 & 15
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
10 & 5 & 30\\ 
0 & -3 & -10\\ 
0 & 0 & -15
\end{pmatrix}$$

For the general form of triangular orthogonal matrices, refer to:

- [Show which matrices are upper triangular orthogonal in $\mathbb R$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/758056/505767)

Comment: Just mentioning that the only upper triangular orthogonal  matrices are diagonal matrices with $\pm 1$ entries on the diagonal.

Comment: @MartinR Nice note, I add a reference on that. I'm wonder for other smart ways to find solutions other than these trivial ones.

Comment: Now if we wanted to move a step further, and assume that we want all cells to be positive we could still find a matrix with the same singular values?

Comment: @Jonathan1234 I think so, since we have many degree of freedom but I can't find a straightforward way to show that. Maybe we can show algebrically that infinitely many solution exist. I'll try something on that asap.